Generating RSA key for a random ciphertext that will decrypt it to a fixed plaintext
According to this cryptopals challenge:
Since RSA signing and decryption are equivalent operations, you can
use this same technique for other surprising results. Try generating a
random (or chosen) ciphertext and creating a key to decrypt it to a
plaintext of your choice!

Does it mean that it is possible to find a RSA key that will decrypt a random ciphertext string, let's say generated by this command cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 100 | head -n 1 to a given fixed plaintext, for example: "Hello World".
Please correct me, if my understanding of this idea is wrong.

Yes, but your RSA key does not meet the standards.
You have some random $c$ and you want to create a key such that decryption of $c$ with this key results specific $m$.
$c^d \equiv m $ $(mod$ $N)$ where $ N = p * q $
This results:
$c^d \equiv m $ $(mod$ $p)$ and
$c^d \equiv m $ $(mod$ $q)$
We only know $m$ and $c$ in this setting, we want to pick some $p$, $q$, $d$ that satisfy these congruences.
As stated in your reference, we have to pick some $p$ and $q$ such that $p-1$ and $q-1$ are smooth numbers. Because our congruences are nothing but discrete logarithm problems. For $c^d \equiv m $ $(mod$ $p)$, we know $c$, $m$, and $p$ but it is still hard to find $d$ in the case of $(p-1)$ has a large prime factor.
If we can pick some suitable $p$ and $q$, we can find $d_1$ and $d_2$ that satisfy:
$c^{d_1} \equiv m $ $(mod$ $p)$ and  $c^{d_2} \equiv m $ $(mod$ $q)$ by using Pohlig–Hellman algorithm.
Then we can find $d$ by using Chinese Remainder Theorem from:
$ d \equiv {d_1} $ $(mod$ $p-1)$
$ d \equiv {d_2} $ $(mod$ $q-1)$
Our $d$ satisfies $c^d \equiv m $ $(mod$ $N)$. We can find $e$ the standard way.
